# Get all links in a site and all subsites using Powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

We have a public facing site
 www.productsMainsite.com is our main web application

i need only pages and sites information for a site under a web application, for example: 
www.productsMainsite.com/prodSite
www.productsMainsite.com/prodSite/Prodcut1
- www.productsMainsite.com/prodSite/product1/pages/page1.aspx
www.productsMainsite.com/prodSite/Prodcut2
-www.productsMainsite.com/prodSite/Prodcut2/pages.page1.aspx

1. How to get all sub sites in a site?
2. How to get all pages in a sub site and a site ?
   using power shell or from Central administration site

and

in this public facing site some pages static and dynamic how i get this information from power shell?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, I have tried rewording it but I still not fully grasp it. Can you please try to edit it to clarify it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
## SharePoint DLL  
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$webApplicationURL = Read-Host "Enter Web application"
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication $webApplicationURL

if($webApp -ne $null)
{
    #Write-Host "Web Application : " + $webApp.Name
    foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
    {
        if($siteColl -ne $null)
        {
            Write-Host -foregroundcolor red "Site Collection: "$siteColl.Url
            Get-SPSite $siteColl | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, Url
        }
        else
        {
            Echo $siteColl "does not exist"
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host  $webApplicationURL "does not exist, check the WebApplication name"
}
```

Comment: hi how i use this code, please can you guide me, and how i display which page is dynamic and static?

Comment: 1.Copy the code
2.Change the webapplication url 
3.paste the code in powershell and run it.

Comment: Hi i need only sitemap information for a site under a webapplication, for example: https://www.productweb.com/prodSite

Comment: HI here in the code how to extend the width of the url et-SPSite $siteColl | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, Url

Answer (score 0):

```
#Retrieve all site collection infos
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminUrl -Credential $Credentials
$sitesInfo = Get-SPOSite

#Retrieve and print all sites
foreach ($site in $sitesInfo)
{
    Write-Host 'Site collection:' $site.Url
    $AllWebs = Get-SPOWebs -Url $site.Url -Credential $SPOCredentials
    $AllWebs | %{ Write-Host $_.Title }
    Write-Host '-----------------------------'
}
```

Comment: what is sposite in  Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminUrl -Credential $Credentials

Comment: $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", $password)

$AdminUrl  = "https://site/sites/test"

Comment: i get error when run above line PS C:\Users\spadmin> $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Share
PointOnlineCredentials
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate
constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.
At line:1 char:16
+ $credentials = New-Object
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredential ...
+
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: check your user name and password

Comment: Add this line in your top of the code Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Comment: should i run this code in powershell ? and how i import all results in Notepad or xml file with full width of the urls?

Comment: This code will save all the details in your powershell window,so run the below code first then run your powershell  code.
Start-Transcript c:\resuts.txt -Append

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: when i enter username password i faced below error New-Object : Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "xxxxxxxx", for
"SharePointOnlineCredentials" to type "System.Security.SecureString": "Cannot
convert the "xxxxxxx" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Security.SecureString"."
At C:\files\\Po2.ps1:3 char:16

Comment: @adilahmed are you using SharePoint Online? Your question is tagged as sharepoint-server and 2013. But this code will work only with SharePoint Online.

Comment: this is sharepoint 2013 On Premise,